# Please verify that my thinking about this struct related thing is correct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, verify

```
struct Person *person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who!=NULL);

    who->name=strdup(name);
    who->age=age;
    who->height=height;
    who->weight=weight;      
    return who;
}
```

I'm going through ex16 on http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html, and I am not entirely sure I understand this block of code.

As far as I can tell, going line by line, this code does the following:

1. Declare function that returns a `Person`, which takes the arguments `*name`, `age`, `height` and `weight`.
2. Declare a pointer of type `Person` the points to the top on a section of memory big enough to hold a struct of type `Person`.
3. Look at the pointer and determine if it is of type `NULL`.
4. Assign stuff.
5. Return the `who` pointer back to `main()`, so that stuff can happen.

To be honest, I do not understand why `main()` can then access this struct by a name other than `who`. How is the pointer passed? Or is the pointer global somehow?
Or, am I over thinking this?

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is just a number.  It is a memory address.

Suppose you wrote down the address of your house on a piece of paper, put that piece of paper in an envelope, and wrote "who" on the outside. Then, you gave it to someone else, and that person put it in a different envelope, and wrote something different on the outside of the envelope.

Your actual address wouldn't change.  The contents of your house wouldn't change.

It is the same here, in C code.  You are putting the memory address returned by `malloc` in a variable called `who` (analogous to our "envelope".)  You are then modifying something in the memory the address points to.  You are then returning the address to someone who can put it in an entirely different variable with an entirely different name.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Declare function that returns a Person, which takes the arguments
>      *name, age, height and weight.

The function does not return a `Person`. It returns a *pointer* to a `Person`. The arguments are `name`, `age` and `weight`, not `*name`. The star in `*name` means that the argument `name` is of pointer type; it is not part of the argument's name.

> 3. Look at the pointer and determine if it is of type NULL.

`NULL` is not a pointer type. The pointer `who` is a pointer to `struct person`. Here, we are determining if the pointer *value* is `NULL`.

Note that `strdup()` can return `NULL` if no memory is available, just like `malloc()`. The code should probably check for that too.

As for how the pointer is passed to main: you return it from `person_create()` back to `main()`, so `main()` gets to choose how to access it. `main()` can do something like this:

```
/* ... */
struct Person *new_person = create_person(...);

/* Use new_person->age, etc. */
```

The point is, `main()` is free to choose the name it wants to give to whatever `person_create()` returns. It doesn't matter what you had inside `person_create()`, since as soon as you return, local variable names are destroyed.